# Why is my javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just moved an old site from another web developer. He was using CMS made simple. I did copy the full site and included the database. Everything is working fine, except one thing: the photo slider.

The old (working website)
http://hobosolutions.nl

The new (not fully working website)
http://www.cristofoli-design.com/HOBO3/

I'm not really into CMS Made Simple.. but I found some code:

```
{cms_jquery}
<script src="scripts/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "/images/bg/";
var images = [
url+"bg1.jpg",
url+"bg2.jpg"
];

$( document ).ready(function() {
$.backstretch(images, {
        fade: 750,
        duration: 4000
    });
});
</script>
{literal}
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m).   {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 ga('create', 'UA-33493693-14', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');
```

```
  {/literal}
{global_content name='fonts'}
```

I used this code in both sites.. But only one site will work.

Somebody have an solution?

Comment: `var url = location.pathname + "images/bg/";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resides in the fact that you used the same path to image folder in both sites.

In the first site your path to image folder is valid, in fact

> website_url/images/bg/bg1.jpg

is a valid path to the image called "bg1.jpg".
But in the other site, the images array contains invalid paths. I.e. the first element of the array has url

> /images/bg/bg1

, and the corresponding global url is http://www.cristofoli-design.com/images/bg/bg1.jpg, and as you can see it'a 404 page.

My guess is that in the second site files are in different positions.
Keeping guessing, I think you placed the "images" folder inside the "HOBO3" folder, which is not what you are accessing right now.